# Create pages inside custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have archive pages and single pages running good, I would need custom pages inside them too. For example, `www.site.com/dates` is archive page, and `www.site.com/dates/product1` is single page. I would need pages for months too, so `www.site.com/dates/january`, `www.site.com/dates/february` etc. should be working.

```
$months = array('january', 'february', 'march', ...);

$args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Dates',  
        ),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'dates'
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt')
    );
register_post_type('date-posttype', $args);


foreach(months as $month)
{
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array('name' => $month),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'sort' => true,
        'query_var' => $month_var
        );
    register_taxonomy($month_var, 'date-posttype', $args);
}
```

I can probably get with custom code for showing data when these months pages are working, but how do I get them to work?

Comment: Anyone knows how to reach this result? I know the post is very old...